# Split a string of chr into a list (Python)

Tags: string, list, split, char

I just read the 10th line from file 'text.txt'

```
>>>line=linecache.getline("text.txt",10)
>>>line
"['\\x02', '\\x03']\n"
```

I would like to create a list **lst** in this case of two variable '\\x02' and '\\x03'

```
>>>lst
['\\x02','\\x03']
```

I have to iterate the process for different text lines always formatted like **line** also with more variables.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take a string in that format with an arbitrary number of elements and convert it to a list.

```
line = "['\\x02', '\\x03']\n"
line = line.strip()[1:-1]
lst = [x.strip()[1:-1] for x in line.split(",")]
```